# How to Retreive Standard Google Map Lat/Lng

Tags: visualforce, google-map

I have my VFP where user can search the address as shown in the attached screen shot and the marker pops-up once it selected the address, this is all good but my question is:

How can I get the lat/log of that address?, once I get that lat/log I will be saving that to my custom object.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Tugce Sirin is absolutely correct. But i wish to point out few pain points in that approach.

1. The Geocode API of Google is having a limit of 2500 API incoming calls from a URL source per day. So if your salesforce instance is in na6.salesforce.com, the 2500 API incoming calls is applicable if anyone from na6.salesforce.com makes a call to Geocode API
2. We faced lot of issue if the limit is exceeded, it won't give a proper error message but won't return any JSON result at all. Our users in production got frustrated with map not being populated and the functionality completed breaks.

So my suggestion is to use Google Maps Javascript API which doesn't makes any API calls to Google end point and thus doesn't have any API limits.

You can get the details from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

You can get the basic information on how to use Google Map Javascript API in [ForceGuru](http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2012/01/integrating-google-maps-in-salesforce.html) blog post and [BlogForce9](http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2012/09/integrating-google-maps-with-salesforce.html) blog post.

Comment: 1+ I don't know much about maps but do you have any blog or site that is related with google maps javascript api with visualforce page

Comment: Updted the answer to include the links for blog posts which include sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a callout to google api to get geolocation info. You'll need to add http://maps.googleapis.com to Remote Site Settings to make this callout. Below code gets lat/lon info for a given address.

```
            Http h = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&sensor=false');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setTimeout(60000);

            try{
                // callout
                HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

                // parse coordinates from response
                JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
                double lat = null;
                double lon = null;
                while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                    if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) &&
                        (parser.getText() == 'location')){
                           parser.nextToken(); // object start
                           while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT){
                               String txt = parser.getText();
                               parser.nextToken();
                               if (txt == 'lat')
                                   lat = parser.getDoubleValue();
                               else if (txt == 'lng')
                                   lon = parser.getDoubleValue();
                           }

                    }
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

Comment: is this your blog http://www.vandeveldejan.com/trigger-geolocation-account-google-map-nearby-accounts/ ? I have read that blog and the code you posted as the exact code too